# varkappa: amssymb AND kpfonts

Tags: math-fonts, kpfonts

Between the two packages `amssymb` and `kpfonts`, whichever is loaded last determines the look of `\varkappa`.  With the usual tricks using `\let` and `\LetLtxMacro`, I have not found a way to simultaneously have both `amssymb`'s `\varkappa` and `kpfonts`'

> How can I have both versions of `\varkappa` available within a given document?

So far, I've been able to ascertain that the second package (whichever one that might be at the given compile time) redefines what AMSb is/does, but how to use that information is presently beyond my capacity.

Comment: So what is the actual question?  Can you make it into something more precise?

Comment: Do you really want to use *both* in the same documents?

Comment: One possibility is to, after loading the first package, `\let\altvarkappa\varkappa`.  Then `\varkappa` will be as assigned by the second package, and the other shape can be accessed by `\altvarkappa`.  There may be situations (probably in moving arguments) where additional measures are needed, but others are better able to provide that information.

Comment: Did you see the posting [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/5001)?

Comment: Please advise which math alphabet -- CM or kpfonts -- is supposed to be the main math font and which math alphabet is supposed to serve as the source of the alternative `\varkappa` symbol.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: That would be the kind of "usual trick" I referenced that didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You surely can:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\DeclareSymbolFont{AMSAMSb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\amsvarkappa}{\mathord}{AMSAMSb}{"7B}

\begin{document}

$\varkappa+\amsvarkappa$

\end{document}
```

[image]

I feel sympathetic towards the poor readers that will not be able to distinguish the two symbols.

Comment: Very nice the first kappa :). My upvote.